# Is there a makor for the simcha of a siyum/hachnasas Sefer Torah?

Tags: minhag, sefer-torah, simchah-joy-happiness

I heard once that it says that the simcha of a siyum Sefer Torah is greater than that of a chasunah. Does anyone know if/where this is from?
Also, are there any other פתגמים (gemara, medrash, etc) regarding the simcha of a siyum Sefer Torah?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mi Yodeya. Look at this interesting halacha: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.154.10?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Chpt63g page 119 of Rite and Reason

Comment: @rosends, what are the sources he's quoting there? (52-55)

Comment: Both point to אוצר כל מנהגי ישורון רב אברהם אליעזר הירשאוויץ, סט. לואיז, תרעײז both to 47:7